# Google App Engine Back End URL Access from AJAX Call

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

Hi. I was trying to access backend URL from an AJAX call and here's my code, but there's something wrong in the code it preventing me from access the backend URL can anyone help?

```
$.ajax({
  type : "GET",
  url : "http://backend.appid.appspot.com/updateuser/",
  cache: false,
  data : $("#userform").serialize(),
  success : function (msg) {}
});
```

Comment: are you making the requestion from the same domain? (http://backend.appid.appspot.com)

Comment: back-end goes as a sub   domain

Comment: See this: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules).

Comment: @DanielRoseman You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the url to '/updateuser/' and try it out again. Note that you can make Ajax queries only to the same host where document was loaded (same origin policy).

Add also error handler in your call to get some debug info.